# processing jms message in wso2 esb

Tags: jms, wso2, ibm-mq, wso2-esb

I have the JMS message as

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<content>
    <entry type="1">
        <textMessage JMSDeliveryMode="2" JMSDestination="queue:///QUEUE" JMSExpiration="0" JMSMessageID="ID:c3e2d840d8e3c1f14040404040404040cf1eba01c4eff036" JMSPriority="4" JMSRedelivered="false" JMSTimestamp="1434705226223" fromQueue="true" codec="Base64">
            <text>dGVzdA==</text>
        </textMessage>
    </entry>
</content>
```

but when i pull it into wso2 esb it gets into soap envelope and i'm not able to retrieve the properties over here, like JMSDestination etc.
I want to read those details in WSO2 ESB. Is there a way?
I get the following SOAP message after getting the message from JMS, and it is logging or the xPath works only on this.

```html
[2015-06-22 11:08:33,632]  INFO - LogMediator To: , WSAction: urn:mediate, SOAPA
ction: urn:mediate, MessageID: ID:c3e2d840d8e3c1f14040404040404040cf224f7f3bbf47
25, Direction: request, Envelope: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv
:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Bod
y>test1</soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us your wso2 proxy that reads from the queue? Then you can access the your element with a XPath expression like this: `<property name="JMSDestination" expression="$body/content/entry/textMessage/@JMSDestination"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm setting the JMS headers in my sending proxy like this.

In the receiving proxy, you can then access the property with get-property like in the following example.

```
   <log level="custom">
        <property name="Autodeploy_TSONL_CreateProxyTarget - Config Params transport intervall "
                  expression="get-property('transport','TRANSPORT_TRANSFERINTERVALL')"/>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Somehow the source for setting the header wasn't shown in my answer. Hope this time it works.   <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="TRANSPORT_TRANSFERINTERVALL" expression="get-property('result_transferintervall')" scope="transport" type="STRING"></property>

Answer (score 0):

You can select any information from the message body (even if there is a soap envelope for internal purposes) with the following code in your inSequence:

```
<property name="JMSDestination" expression="$body/content/entry/textMessage/@JMSDestination"/>
```

Verify that your message is being build with an appropriate message builder, otherwise you can't see the message content. See this JMS Proxy example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="JMSProxyName" transports="jms" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <log level="custom">
                <property name="Log JMSDestination" expression="$body/content/entry/textMessage/@JMSDestination"/>
            </log>
            <drop/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">
        <rules>
            <jmsProperty>contentType</jmsProperty>
            <default>application/xml</default>
        </rules>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">YourQueue</parameter>
</proxy>
```

Comment: it returns nothing, whatever the expression we give it is taking for the SOAP return message only and not for what I have mentioned as JMS message

Comment: Put a `<log level="full"/>` as a first mediator in the inSequence and check your content.

Comment: it will only give the soap envelope with message, thanks man I have got how to access those property